# Prove that there is no homomorphism from $S_5$ onto a group of order $24$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

Prove that there is no homomorphism from $S_5$ onto a group of order $24$.

**My solution:**

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G|=24.$

Denote $\phi: S_5\to G$.

The normal subgroups of $S_5$ are $S_5,A_5,\{e\}$.

Let $\phi$ be a groups homomorphism.

Denote $\operatorname{Ker(\phi)}=S_5 , A_5, \text{or } \{e\}$

Using the first isomorphism theorem, $S_5/{\rm Ker}(\phi) \cong{\rm Im}(\phi) \implies \frac{|S_5|}{|{\rm Ker}(\phi)|}=|{\rm Im}(\phi)|$.

In case $\operatorname{Ker(\phi)}=S_5 \implies |{\rm Im}(\phi)|=1\neq 24$.

In case $\operatorname{Ker(\phi)}=A_5 \implies |{\rm Im}(\phi)|=2\neq 24$.

In case $\operatorname{Ker(\phi)}=\{e\} \implies |{\rm Im}(\phi)|=5!\neq 24$.

Hence, there is no homomorphism $\phi$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: @Evan_Bradley Sorry , it was a typo , thanks.

Comment: You should say in the text that $\phi$ is surjective. Otherwise there is a homomorphism $\phi$.

Comment: This seems mostly right, but forgive me if I’m wrong, but I believe you’ve only proved there are no surjective homomorphisms from $S_5$ to a group of order $24$. For example, the trivial homomorphism $\varphi: S_5 \rightarrow S_4$, with $\varphi(a)=e$ for all $a\in S_5$ seems to be a homomorphism between $S_5$ and a group of order $24$.

Comment: An other approach is to first show that $S_5$ is generated by a $5$-cycle $\sigma$ and a transposition $\tau$, so its image is generated by $\varphi(\sigma)$ and $\varphi(\tau)$. The image of $\sigma$ must have order dividing both $5$ and $24$, so it must be $e$. Then all elements of $S_5$ are mapped to $e$ or $\varphi(\tau)$ so $\varphi$ is not onto.

Comment: Your argument seems to me to be OK. But it uses a big theorem "the only normal subgroups of $S_5$ are ..." when you need only use a trivial one "A subgroup of $S_5$ of order $5$ is generated by a $5$-cycle, and as all $5$ cycles are conjugate the subgroup can't be normal".